# Need more than one of the same jQuery effect on same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

So I'm using this jquery background scroller, basically I want to get more than two on the same page (going at different speeds) and I can't figure out how to do it.

http://www.devirtuoso.com/2009/07/how-to-build-an-animated-header-in-jquery/

```
var scrollSpeed = 70;       // Speed in milliseconds
var step = 1;               // How many pixels to move per step
var current = 0;            // The current pixel row
var imageHeight = 4300;     // Background image height
var headerHeight = 300;     // How tall the header is.

//The pixel row where to start a new loop
var restartPosition = -(imageHeight - headerHeight);

function scrollBg(){

    //Go to next pixel row.
    current -= step;

    //If at the end of the image, then go to the top.
    if (current == restartPosition){
        current = 0;
    }

    //Set the CSS of the header.
    $('#header').css("background-position","0 "+current+"px");


}

//Calls the scrolling function repeatedly
var init = setInterval("scrollBg()", scrollSpeed);
```

I can add in other css to the script but I want a different speed for other divs.

Comment: You could create a plugin...I suggest you take a look at the plugin authoring guide at the jquery site.

Comment: Why not just factor all of the above into its own object, then you could simply instantiate multiple instances, passing in the scroll speed, div tag, etc?

Comment: Honestly, authoring a plugin is a bit beyond me, I'm really just getting started with jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@andy, here is Tom Th's idea worked up; ie a js constructor function, from which you can instantiate multiple instances :

```
function bgScroller(options) {
    var settings = {
        containerID: '', //id of the scroller's containing element
        scrollSpeed: 50, //Speed in milliseconds
        step: 1, //How many pixels to move per step
        imageHeight: 0, //Background image height
        headerHeight: 0, //How tall the header is.
        autoStart: true
    };
    if(options) {
        jQuery.extend(settings, options);
    }
    var current = 0, // The current pixel row
        restartPosition = -(settings.imageHeight - settings.headerHeight), //The pixel row where to start a new loop 
        interval = null,
        $container = jQuery('#' + settings.containerID),
        that = {};
    if(!$container.length || !settings.imageHeight || !settings.headerHeight) {
        return false; //nothing will work without these settings so let's not even try
    }
    function setBg() {
        $container.css("background-position", "0 " + current + "px");
    }
    function scrollBg(){
        current -= settings.step;//Go to next pixel row.
        //If at the end of the image, then go to the top.
        if (current <= restartPosition){
            current = 0;
        }
        setBg();
    }
    that.reset = function() {
        that.stop();
        current = 0;
        setBg();
    }
    that.start = function() {
        interval = setInterval(scrollBg, settings.scrollSpeed);
    };
    that.stop = function(){
        clearInterval(interval);
    };
    that.reset();
    if(settings.autoStart) {
        that.start();
    }
    return that;
}
```

Parameters are passed as properties of an object literal "map", overriding the hard-coded defaults in the constructor. For any parameters not included, the default values will be used. Here's a couple of examples :

```
var headerScroller = new bgScroller({
    containerID: "header",
    scrollSpeed: 70, //Speed in milliseconds
    imageHeight: 4300, //Background image height
    headerHeight: 300, //How tall the header is.
});
var otherScroller = new bgScroller({
    containerID: "myOtherDiv",
    scrollSpeed: 30, //Speed in milliseconds
    imageHeight: 2800, //Background image height
    headerHeight: 200, //How tall the header is.
});
```

I have included three public methods; `.reset()`, `.start()` and `.stop()`, which provide limited control over scrollers after instantiation. Use as follows:

- `headerScroller.stop();`
- `headerScroller.reset();`
- `headerScroller.start();`

Notes:

- Working demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/VfMkt/3/).
- Dependencies: jQuery 1.0 or later
- `.reset()` calls `.stop()` automatically so there's no need to call `.stop()` beforehand.
- No provision is made for changing settings after instantiation but this would be possible with a little more thought.
- jQuery plugin would be similar but would take a little more time to develop (with little advantage).

Comment: Wow! What an amazing answer, beetroot. Thanks for that.
The only problem is as soon as i paste it in I get a code error on this line  
var current: 0, // The current pixel row

You'll have to forgive me but most of what you said went over my head.

Comment: Now tested and debugged. Answer above edited to reflect the revised code. See link to Demo in the notes.

Comment: I cannot get this to work outside of jsfiddle in any way.

Here's my code http://pastebin.com/pSQjkuvR 

Works great in jsfiddle and can change it to my liking but it won't work on my own docs?

Comment: In jsFiddle the `onDomReady` framework setting establishes an invisible wrapper around the javaScript code. Outside jsFiddle, you have to do the same (but not invisibly), by wrapping in `$(function(){...});`, where `...` is all the other code.

Comment: Done it like this http://pastebin.com/qeFrnbX7

Still doesn't work I'm afraid. :(

Comment: Some bad characters have managed to creep into the code. They show as question marks in Notepad++. Paste the whole page into Notepad or Notepad++ and you should see them - 3 in number - last line of stylesheet, last line of script block, and after `<div id="header"></div>`. Remove them and the page should work.

Comment: Well I got it working, but I can't use it, things get really screwy when you try to stop and start times, or the scroll speed.
You can't accurately get them to stop at the right time.

Comment: Thanks for all your help beetroot, but I don't think I can use this in it's current iteration.

Comment: I can't see why it shouldn't work. I can only think it's to do with the way the options map is constructed or the way the methods are called. To stop, simply call eg, `headerScroller.stop();` and it will stop immediately. Don't use `setTimeout(headerScroller.stop, xxx)`; as in the demo, unless you want to schedule `.stop()` at some point in the future. The setTimeouts in the demo are for demo purposes - while developing, they avoided the need for buttons to

Comment: to .... call the `.start()`, `.stop()` and `.reset()` methods. In general, you may never need to call these methods, with the (default) option `autoStsrt: true`, the scrolling will start automatically and never stop.